# How to retrieve firebase database?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can not retrieve firebase database from Java (non android). I have created firebase database as follow:

[image]
Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("D:/xxxxxxxxxx-x9314-firebase-adminsdk-d8he2-4ab7b5976b.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://xxxxxxxxx-x9314.firebaseio.com/")
            .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference("cars");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Object car = dataSnapshot.getValue();
        System.out.println(car);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
      }
    });
}
```

There is no data appear when I run the application.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Have you tried to print the `error`? What is the output?

Comment: I found no error on the console

Comment: You need to print it. Your onCancelled is empty. Add a print statement.

Comment: Hi Alex... thanks for your comments. I want to print the log of firebase, how it create connection ect. But I have not found yet the library needed (firebase analytics) for debugging. There is no in maven repository.

Comment: Do you have a "Car" object?